# Creating a Subtotal calculator in JavaScript (in a model)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a subtotal calculator using JavaScript that would automatically multiply the price (in £) of a certain product by the quantity selected by the user.

I have been at this for a few days now. I am working with a constructor and am trying to modify its code. I have tried several approaches using JavaScript and so far none of them worked.

Here is the HTML code I have added to the product page:

```
 <div class="data">
 <input class="form-input form-input--incrementTotal"
           id="qty[]"
           name="qty[]"
           type="number"
           value="{{#if product.min_purchase_quantity}}   {{product.min_purchase_quantity}}{{else}}1{{/if}}"
           data-quantity-min="{{product.min_purchase_quantity}}"
           data-quantity-max="{{product.max_purchase_quantity}}"
           min="1"
           pattern="[0-9]*"
           aria-live="polite">
    <span id="price" data-product-price-without-tax class="price price--withoutTax{{#if price.with_tax}} price-section--minor{{/if}}">{{price.without_tax.formatted}}</span>
    <span id="price1" class=price1></span>
    <div id="total" class="total"></div> 
    <div id="total1" class="total1"></div>
 </div
```

Approach 1:

```
 <script>
    var priceRange = document.getElementById("qty[]").value;
    var priceAmount = $('#price').html();
    var removeEuro = priceAmount.replace("£", "");
    var total = parseFloat(removeEuro) * parseFloat(priceRange);
    $('#total').text('£' + total);
 </script>
```

Approach 2:

```
 <script>
 var price1 = parseFloat($("#price").text().split('£')[1]);
 $("#price1").text(price1);
 var r, i;
 r = document.getElementsByClassName("data");
 for(i=0;i<r.length; i++){
 r[i].getElementsByClassName("total")[0].innerHTML =
    r[i].getElementsByClassName("price1")[0].innerText *
    r[i].getElementsByClassName("form-input--incrementTotal")   [0].value;
 }
 function total(element) {
 var tr = element.parentNode.parentNode;
 var price = tr.getElementsByClassName("form-input--incrementTotal")   [0].innerText;
 tr.getElementsByClassName("total")[0].innerHTML = price *    element.value;
 }
 function sumTotal(){
 var tot = 0 ; 
 var len = document.getElementsByClassName("total").length;
 for(var i =0; i<len; i++){ 
 tot += parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("total") [i].innerText); 
 }
 }
 $('#total1').html('£' + parseFloat($('#total').text()))
 </script>
```

Neither of the approaches worked. I keep getting an NaN error. I do not understand why it's telling me the result is not a number. Perhaps {{price.without_tax.formatted}} could be what's causing the issue? Can someone please help me with my code?

Comment: `removeEuro = priceAmount.replace("£", "");` - like you joke :)

Comment: More seriously you need to provide [MCVE] along with exact data you feed into methods. There is really no way to know what `price.without_tax.formatted` contains for example. Just show function that take a string and show what exact value you pass to it.

Comment: If I change price.without_tax.formatted and input value to numeric values, everything works as it should. The problem I have is that because I am trying to modify a constructor I can’t just use a single value as there multiple products and I am wroting a general code for all of them.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov maybe I need to extract a value from price object and property `{{price.without_tax.formatted}}` and then use it in my code?